# Is it possible to prevent Singleton-components from using PerThread-components then using castle-windsor?

Tags: c#, .net, castle-windsor, ioc-container

Is it possible to prevent castle-windsor to satisfy a singleton-component's dependencies with per-thread components? I have looked at sub-dependency-resolvers and handler-selectors but can't figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Have you tried registering the same component multiple times with different names and life cycles, and then request the one you need?

Comment: @Alexander: What the OP wants is to be able to analyse the dependency graph to detect configuration errors, because the lifetime of a dependency must always be equal to or greater than the lifetime of the consumer.

Comment: I don't understand the question. If you don't want to use “per-thread” components, you have to use some other component instead.  Or do you want it to fail in this case?

Answer (score 0):

It is an interesting idea. I suspect you might use service overrides to redirect the dependency from your singleton to some other singleton and have a test to ensure that's applied across the board.

Comment: It would be nice to use a tool as http://code.google.com/p/whitebox/. It is currently in alpha and for Autofac only, but it would be interesting to have a single tool (such as Whitbox) with plugins for several DI frameworks to be able to analyse the dependency graph of any application.

Comment: @Steven, I agree, and I spoke to Nick (author of both Autofac and Whitebox) about this already. Whitebox is engineered in such a way that the core of it has no knowledge of Autofac so you can plug other frameworks in. It's just no one stepped in to lead the effort to build Windsor profiling in. If you'd be interested, let me know.

Comment: Well actually, I'd be at first interested in building a plugin for the Simple Injector.